# Does SQL standard specify the order of constraint validation and trigger firing?

Tags: sql

I'm curious if I can rely on any particular order of validating `NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY, UNIQUE, CHECK` constraints and `BEFORE` triggers.

From experience I know that MySQL first checks `NOT NULL`, then launches `BEFORE` trigger, and then checks `UNIQUE` constraints. Oracle checks `NOT NULL` after the `BEFORE` trigger ( I believe SQLServer does the same, but don't remember). Does the standard say anything about the order or it's completely up to DB vendor?

Comment: Oracle does **not** check NOT NULL until after `before` triggers. That allows the `before` trigger to change the values such that they are no longer not null.

Comment: @Shannon Severance : Yeah, sorry, I was thinking about mysql... Fixed

Comment: You could download a [draft](http://www.wiscorp.com/sql200n.zip) (Link taken from Wikipedia) of the most recent standard and look through it yourself (I can't find any such definitions)

Comment: In SQL Server the order is `Instead Of Trigger Entered ,Check NULL constraint, Unique constraints, check constraints, FK, After Trigger, Instead Of Trigger Exited` from testing I did to answer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7665022/73226)

Comment: This is clearly an implementation detail though so I extremely doubt the standard would have anything at all to say on it.

Comment: @ Martin Smith: Thanks for the link and SQLServer order... I thought it may be some 'normal' order. In practice, I mostly interested in `BEFORE TRIGGER`(surely, if RMDS supports it) vs constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular behavior seems to be a [bug in MySQL](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6295), and it only affects `BEFORE INSERT` triggers, while `BEFORE UPDATE` triggers behave correctly.

The [standard](http://www.wiscorp.com/sql200n.zip) (as linked in question comments) certainly doesn't spell it out explicitly, but it's definitely implied:

> For each state change SCi,j in TECi, the BEFORE triggers activated by SCi,j are executed before any of their
>   triggering events take effect. When those triggering events have taken effect, any AFTER triggers activated by
>   the state changes of TECi are executed.

A `NOT NULL` error should be part of an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` (i.e. the triggering event).  The standard should not need to specify this.  There is absolutely *no point* to pre-emptively checking constraints on a set of changes which is not final because your `BEFORE` trigger is capable of both  resolving errors *and* introducing new ones.

**SUMMARY: It really isn't up to the DB vendor because checking constraints after a before trigger is *always* necessary.**