# In what order does SQL Server evaluate unique indexes and can it be controlled?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I take action depending on what unique indexes failed and want certain index validation failures to happen first if multiple unique indexes meet the criteria for failure.

Engine checks uniqueness of unique constraint.

What if there are multiple unique constraints? Can I control what order it checks them in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL and transaction flow - from first to last](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665022/t-sql-and-transaction-flow-from-first-to-last)

Comment: No, there's no means of controlling which constraints get checked before others.